# Code::Blocks is not making object files for Boost Filesystem in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I've been struggling to get Boost compiled libraries such as Filesystem working on my Windows 10 laptop using Code Blocks 16- 01

The simple basic code I've been using is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main ()

{
    cout << "HEllo World" << endl;
    cout << "Testing if \"C:\\Hello.txt\" exists" << endl;

    boost::filesystem::path l_path("c:\\Hello.txt");

    if ( boost::filesystem::exists(l_path) )

    {
        cout << "File does exist!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File missing" << endl;
    }

}
```

This gives a rebuild log of:

> mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -Weffc++ -pedantic -Wextra   -Wall -std=c++11 -pg -g -I"C:\Program Files\boost_1_61_0\" -c C:\Users\brend\Dropbox\PhD\Code\LBM\testboost1\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o

with the following error message:

> mingw32-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files

Inspecting the debug folder, no main.o file is being created.

Other set up information includes: the Boost root is  "C:\Program Files\boost_1_61_0\"
The search directories specified in C::B include 
Compiler: "C:\Program Files\boost_1_61_0\"
Linker: "C:\Program Files\boost_1_61_0\stage\lib"

I'm linking the following libraries: libboost_filesystem-mgw51-mt-d-1_61.a and libboost_system-mgw51-mt-d-1_61.a

I've also tried reinstalling Code::Blocks and MinGW to no effect.

Many thanks for any help in Advance!!

Comment: I would try putting the files in some other place then in a dropbox folder just in case it matters.

Comment: Thanks J.J. for your comment but unfortunately this does not work. Any other thoughts?